# USB connection with PIC18F4550

Tags: usb, pic

I'm building a circuit of PIC18F4550 and trying to connect to PC as an HID device. It has already worked for once (the circuit was correctly recognized and installed on PC) but afterwards something wrong happened with the circuit and I had to rebuild it. However, it no longer can be recognized on PC although I checked the connections and replaced almost all the components including the PIC, and the code supposedly works fine. I just noticed that when I measure VUSB, the AVO gives about 0 V although it is supposed to be 3.3V as the USB internal regulator is enabled. Any hints, please? Thanks a lot
Edit: Here is the schematic I'm following.
[image]

Edit: Here is the project settings in MikroC Pro for PIC
[image]

Comment: Adding schematic will be effective than oral explanation

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have added the schematic in the post.

Comment: What are the steps you'd followed to turn on the internal regulator? You need to enable USBEN register and VREGEN register. Have you checked it?

Comment: @CNA I have enabled the internal regulator in the project settings in MikroC Pro fpor PIC. Is this sufficient?

Comment: Project settings mean what?

Comment: You have to enable those two registers in your firmware. Have you read the data sheet of this microcontroller?

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the project settings that I mean. Please, have a look. Thank you very much for your concern.

Comment: I am not familiar with Mikro C but with data sheet. So, I asked. Is this enough for enabling internal regulator? Datasheet tell about the usb registers. Is this a setting you have successfully used in HID mode? Don't you change anything in your firmware?